# Subtracting minimum of row from the row

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I know that

a - a.min(axis=0)

will subtract the minimum of each column from every element in the column. I want to subtract the minimum in each row from every element in the row. I know that

a.min(axis=1)

specifies the minimum within a row, but how do I tell the subtraction to go by rows instead of columns? (How do I specify the axis of the subtraction?)

edit: For my question, a is a 2d array in NumPy.

Comment: What type of object is `a`?

Comment: 2d numpy array.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `a` is a numpy array, you can use this:

```
new_a = a - np.min(a, axis=1)[:,None]
```

**Try it out:**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(24).reshape((4,6))
print (a)
new_a = a - np.min(a, axis=1)[:,None]
print (new_a)
```

**Result:**

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23]]
[[0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 1 2 3 4 5]]
```

Note that `np.min(a, axis=1)` returns a 1d array of row-wise minimum values.

We than add an extra dimension to it using `[:,None]`. It then looks like this 2d array:

```
array([[ 0],
       [ 6],
       [12],
       [18]])
```

When this 2d array participates in the subtraction, it gets broadcasted into a shape of `(4,6)`, which looks like this:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6],
       [12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12],
       [18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18]])
```

Now, element-wise subtraction happens between the two `(4,6)` arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Specify `keepdims=True` to preserve a length-1 dimension in place of the dimension that `min` collapses, allowing broadcasting to work out naturally:

```
a - a.min(axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

This is especially convenient when `axis` is determined at runtime, but still probably clearer than manually reintroducing the squashed dimension even when the `1` value is fixed.

Comment: ValueError: the 'keepdims' parameter is not supported in the pandas implementation of min()

Comment: I getthe following ValueError

Comment: @AlessandroSolbiati: If you've got a Pandas dataframe, then yeah, you'd get an error like that, but this kind of operation doesn't make much sense on a Pandas dataframe. My answer was written for NumPy arrays. The questioner really should have specified what the heck `a` is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use only `pandas` you can just apply a lambda to every column using `min(row)`

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    new_df[col] = df.apply(lambda row: row[i] - min(row))
```